# Eclipse signals an error but the code compiles

Tags: eclipse, vector, syntax-error

I'm writing some C++ code with eclipe.

I have a strange behavior with vector objects.

When I use the method `resize` for example, Eclipse returns the following error:

```
#include "vector"

   ...

   vector<int> a;
   a.resize(5);

   Error: Invalid arguments candidates are: void resize(?, int).
```

However the code compiles from command line.

How can I fix this fastidious behavior of eclipse?

Comment: Works for me. Are you using latest CDT? Note that Linux distros tend to package CDT that is a couple years old.

Comment: I am also having this problem. I have added all include directories, and Eclipse doesn't have a problem with `vector<int>`, it's just its member variables it has a problem with.

Answer (score 6):

After quite a while searching and tinkering with settings, I think I have found an answer. To get the indexer parsing the code correctly I had to:

1. Right click the project -> Properties
2. Go to C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc.
3. Click the providers tab
4. Check the **CDT GCC Build-in Compiler Settings** option
5. Apply
6. Rebuild index